# How to center a block of social icon background images?

Tags: html, css, centering

I'm trying to center a block of social icons into the center of the screen when my website is in mobile browser size. My html is:

```
<div id="header-tel-no">Tel: 123456789</div>

<div id="social-buttons-header">
<p><a class="social-button sb-linkedin" href="http://www.linkedin.com/sample" target="_blank">Linkedin</a></p>

<p><a class="social-button sb-twitter" href="https://twitter.com/sample" target="_blank">Twitter</a></p>

<p><a class="social-button sb-facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/sample" target="_blank">Facebook</a></p>

<p><a class="social-button sb-email" href="mailto:info@sample.co.uk">Email</a></p>
</div>
```

My CSS is: -

```
#social-buttons-header{

    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

}

.social-button{

    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    text-indent: -999em;
    display: inline-block;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    margin-right: 2px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}

a.social-button:hover,
.social-button a:hover,
a.social-button:hover:after,
.social-button a:hover:after {

    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid #FF9933;
}


a.social-button.sb-facebook,
.social-button a.sb-facebook {
  background: transparent url(images/facebook.png) no-repeat;

}

a.social-button.sb-twitter,
.social-button a.sb-twitter {
  background: transparent url(images/twitter.png) no-repeat;

}

a.social-button.sb-linkedin,
.social-button a.sb-linkedin {
  background: transparent url(images/linkedin.png) no-repeat;

}

a.social-button.sb-email,
.social-button a.sb-email {
  background: transparent url(images/outlook.png) no-repeat;

}
```

The social icons appear on the right like this...

.................[x][x][x][x]

i want them as ...

........[x][x][x][x] .........

(i have used the above brackets and x's as I cant upload a pic yet, as my score is not high enough)

Can anyone advise how I can get them into the center please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the provided code  - Update `p` tags to display inline-block and center the content of the header

http://jsfiddle.net/vc3tkdq7/

```
p {
    display: inline-block;
}

#social-buttons-header{
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;    
}
```

To remove the text

http://jsfiddle.net/xten2c47/1/

I used `text-indent: 999999px;`

Comment: Or simply remove drop the `<p>` elements within the markup.

Comment: @HashemQolami I assume the tags have purposes when the browser is not viewed in mobile view

Comment: You are right. Just a side-note for the OP: specifying both `width: 100%;` and left/right `margin` of `auto` is pointless.

Comment: @HashemQolami original code from OP, I assume margin left and right and width was set before and the OP needs to reset it. Otherwise it can be removed like you suggested

Comment: I added this but I'm still stuck over on the right...  #social-buttons-header p {
    display: inline-block;
}

#social-buttons-header {
 text-align: center;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

Comment: @CardiffSteve Then other css are in effect and you have not provided the code for them. If you can recreate this on http://jsfiddle.net then it would be a lot easier to trouble shoot

Comment: you are correct, i had
    #social-buttons-header p {
     float: right;
    }
in another css file which gets invoked when I go to narrow/wide screen. If I comment that out, it centers perfectly on mobile, but on narrow/wide screen, it is not right justified which is what I want. If i replace the float:right with a text-align: right 
i get the words facebook, twitter etc over top of the images (due to my text-indent: -999em getting messed up probably.
Any idea how to get it right justified working on narrow/wide without the words appearing over my icons?

Comment: @CardiffSteve I am not sure what you mean by right justified. I suggest you ask another question with an example on fiddle to demonstrate the problem you are having, and the desired result

Comment: How can I remove the writting over my icons, when i use text-align:right for my narrow/wide screen css, this is the jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cardiffsteve/xten2c47/

Comment: i think a positive text-indent is the answer?

Comment: @CardiffSteve You can do `text-indent: 999999px;` or you can add a span wrapping the text and simply display none for the span http://jsfiddle.net/xten2c47/1/ answer is updated

Comment: The positive text-indent value works perfect for me, when using a text-align:right for the narrow/wide css. Thanks for being so helpful. I have also signed-up for jfiddle which will really help me giong forwards. thank you for your help and support. i have ticked this as answered .

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code

```
#social-buttons-header {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center
}
.social-button {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-indent: -999em;
  display: inline-block;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  margin-right: 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}
a.social-button:hover,
.social-button a:hover,
a.social-button:hover:after,
.social-button a:hover:after {
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid #FF9933;
}
a.social-button.sb-facebook,
.social-button a.sb-facebook {
  background: transparent url(images/facebook.png) no-repeat;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
a.social-button.sb-twitter,
.social-button a.sb-twitter {
  background: transparent url(images/twitter.png) no-repeat;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
a.social-button.sb-linkedin,
.social-button a.sb-linkedin {
  background: transparent url(images/linkedin.png) no-repeat;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
a.social-button.sb-email,
.social-button a.sb-email {
  background: transparent url(images/outlook.png) no-repeat;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="header-tel-no">Tel: 123456789</div>
<div id="social-buttons-header">
  <p><a class="social-button sb-linkedin" href="http://www.linkedin.com/sample" target="_blank">Linkedin</a><a class="social-button sb-twitter" href="https://twitter.com/sample" target="_blank">Twitter</a><a class="social-button sb-facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/sample"
    target="_blank">Facebook</a><a class="social-button sb-email" href="mailto:info@sample.co.uk">Email</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

.

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/typecpfy/)